# Какая разница между appendTo и append() ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не понятен результат данного вызова.

Буду рад если кто то сможет объяснить, что должно произойти после вызова `appendTo` ?

Я пытался создать див, присоединить к нему класс и присоеденить сам див к
 body.

Не понятна логика метода и его проперти `appendTo`, для чего используется ?

Рабочий пример:

```
var paragraph =  $("<div>I am here!</div>").addClass("navigation_for_900px");
            $("body").append(paragraph);
```

Какая разница между append() и appendTo в результате ?

```js
 var paragraph =  $("<div>I am here!</div>").addClass("navigation_for_900px");
            paragraph.appendTo ?? при вызове даной проперти что должно произойти ? 


jQuery.each( { // из jquery-3.1.0.js! 
 appendTo: "append",
 prependTo: "prepend",
 insertBefore: "before",
 insertAfter: "after",
 replaceAll: "replaceWith"
}, function( name, original ) {
 jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( selector ) {
  var elems,
   ret = [],
   insert = jQuery( selector ),
   last = insert.length - 1,
   i = 0;

  for ( ; i <= last; i++ ) {
   elems = i === last ? this : this.clone( true );
   jQuery( insert[ i ] )[ original ]( elems );

   // Support: Android <=4.0 only, PhantomJS 1 only
   // .get() because push.apply(_, arraylike) throws on ancient WebKit
   push.apply( ret, elems.get() );
  }

  return this.pushStack( ret );
 };
} );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в направлении действия.

`appendTo` вызывается у элемента, **который** нужно добавить
`append` вызывается у контейнера, **в** который нужно добавить

Для примера можно взять два элемента: А и Б

Если нужно добавить элемент А в элемент Б

можно использовать метод `appendTo`: `A.appendTo(Б)`

Если нужно в элемент Б добавить элемент А

можно использовать метод `append`: `Б.append(А)`

В итоге: результат одинаковый, элемент А находится внутри элемента Б.