# Перенос фокуса в новые contenteditable поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы при создании нового элемента в него переносиля фокус?

https://jsfiddle.net/brachkoff/zfh8wmzr/3/

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Текст задания</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Еще текста</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Какой-то текст</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="interface">
  <button id="add">Add Task</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#list').append('<li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text"></span></li>')
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#list')
    .append('<li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text"></span></li>')
    .find('li:last-child [contenteditable]')
    .focus();
```

Comment: можете подробнее разъяснить что вы делали с .find?

Comment: @brachkoff, нашел необходимый элемент, на который вы планируете установить фокус. Собственно, имя метода - `find` - говорит само за себя - "найти" ))

Comment: @brachkoff, метод `find()` выполняет поиск дочерних элементов. В данном случае, если я не ошибаюсь, поиск выполняется от добавленного элемента `li` (так как `append` возвращает объект `jQuery`, судя по документации). А параметром метода использован селектор, выбирающий элементы с атрибутом `contenteditable`, дочерние по отношению к последнему потомку `li`. Если мои рассуждения верны, то данный код не только малоэффективен, но и содержит ошибку... хотя, он может и работать.

Comment: @yar85, если коротко, то ваши рассуждения не верны. Впрочем, об эффективности библиотеки в целом, действительно говорить сложно.

Comment: @Deonis, об эффективности библиотеки в целом - речи и не было (потому что к данному вопросу это не относится).

Comment: @yar85, я ж не против, чтобы вы дали более оптимальный вариант. )) Что касается моего кода, то я не вижу в нём каких-то проблем. А сделать его эффективным можно, но переписав на нативном JS. Возможно, что вы не так хорошо знакомы с библиотекой, поэтому у вас и возникло ложно ощущение.

Comment: Да, это возможно. А еще возможно, что для ответов состоящих только из кода без пояснений (и для отвлеченных комментов о чьих-либо ощущениях), Вы выбрали не тот веб-ресурс :) Хотите что-то дополнить - пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ... это будет полезнее, чем неконструктивная критика комментария, компенсирующего отсутствие объяснений в ответе. Тем более, если при этом Вы укажете достаточно информации, чтобы и у других не возникало... кхм, ложных ощущений.

Comment: @yar85, почему Вы решили, что я хочу что-то добавить? Даже в мыслях не было. Неконструктивная критика последовала в первую очередь от Вас, а я всего лишь отреагировал. Хотя, правильней сказать, что от вас критика была некомпетентной. Но спорить, что-либо доказывать и еще тратить на этот вопрос время, я не собираюсь. Последнее, что я могу сделать - это [предложить протестировать](https://jsperf.com/append-find-focus) мой вариант и, например, вариант коллеги, который у вас не вызвал возмущения. А в остальном - библиотека и документация в открытом доступе... На этом позвольте откланяться.

Comment: @Deonis, в свою очередь, предложу Вам почитать [tour],
 [answer], и комментарии (внимательно).

Answer (score 3):

Есть метод `focus()`, который предназначен для установки фокуса.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/zfh8wmzr/7/).

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var $el = $('<li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text"></span></li>'); // создаем элемент
  $('#list').append($el); // Добавляем его в список
  $el.find('.task__text').focus(); // Находим редактируемый элемент и устанавливаем фокус
})
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.task__text {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
}

.task__text br {
  display: none;
}

#interface {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Текст задания</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Еще текста</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Какой-то текст</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="interface">
  <button id="add">Add Task</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В добавок к методу [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/), можно изменить построение элементов, чтобы не искать элемент, который мы сами и создаем.

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`appendTo`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) (немного о [разнице между `append` и `appendTo`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587561/186999))

Особенность метода `appendTo` в том, что он возвращает элемент, *который* добавлялся, следовательно к его результату можно применить и метод `focus`.

Пример реализации:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('<span contenteditable="true" class="task__text"></span>').appendTo(
    $('<li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"></li>').appendTo('#list')
  ).focus();
})
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.task__text {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
}

.task__text br {
  display: none;
}

#interface {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Текст задания</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Еще текста</span></li>
  <li class="task"><input type="checkbox" class="task__checkbox"><span contenteditable="true" class="task__text">Какой-то текст</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="interface">
  <button id="add">Add Task</button>
</div>
```